# Webview shows white blank page in Ice Cream Sandwitch

Tags: java, android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In my webview I have loaded a URL which have an embeded video player of a tv channel live stream. It is working correctly in all the OS version of Android except ICS(4). First time It plays the video well, but when I go back and come again in that page containing the video then the video doesnt loads and shows a blank white page. If I force stop the app from the application setting and start the app again then It runs well then appears white screen again as usual, I have implemented a lot of tactics and this is the latest , I am totally stuck here:

```
public class Livetvwebview extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout a;
    WebView webtv;
    String url;
    VideoView video;
    WChromeClient chromeClient;
    WebViewClient wvClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.livewebview);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Channel is loading..This may take upto a minute",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("tvchannel");
        Log.i("TVURL", url);
        webtv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewlive);
        webtv.clearCache(true);
        webtv.loadUrl(url);

        webtv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webtv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webtv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webtv.setWebChromeClient(new WChromeClient());
        webtv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webtv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webtv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        webtv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }



    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebSettings webSettings = webtv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webtv.onPause();
        this.finish();
        super.onPause();

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {



        webtv.onResume();
        super.onResume();

    }






    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("clear_cache",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        trimCache(this);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    class WChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            Log.i("Method", "Onrogresschanged");

            Livetvwebview.this.setTitle("Loading...");
            Livetvwebview.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
            if (progress == 100)
                Livetvwebview.this.setTitle("LiveTv");

        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                    webtv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams par = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    par.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    video.setLayoutParams(par);
                    frame.removeView(video);
                    a.addView(video);
                    video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            Toast.makeText(Livetvwebview.this,
                                    "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        }
                    });

                    video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what,
                                int extra) {
                            Toast.makeText(Livetvwebview.this,
                                    "Encountered some error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    video.start();
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void trimCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching for a long long time I myself figured out that when I write in the onPause()

```
webtv.destroy();
```

instead of

```
webtv.onPause();
```

solves the problem :)