# WebView showing blank white page instead of loading a link

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to open following link in my WebView

http://issuu.com/muhammadumar88/docs/prime_guide_2016?e=27032292/40838888

With code

```
mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        WebSettings websettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; C1905 Build/15.1.C.2.8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36");

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)));
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(link);



public class AppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        public AppWebViewClient(ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

I keep on getting a white blank page. How can i fix it, what am i missing?

Comment: did you set permission in manifest?

Comment: @sasikumar what permission??

Comment: yes.... your AndroidManifest.xml file.

<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

Comment: @sasikumar not internet issue, the player is not loading, other websites work fine

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706580/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the following line.

```
 mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

instead of

```
mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(webView);
```

For More information please Refer [Webview shows white blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750798/webview-shows-white-blank-page-in-ice-cream-sandwitch?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry i fixed it, the result is same, the video is not loading, all other websites are loading